# I have this Warning format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type int *

Tags: c

Hello World i'm totally new to C and im trying to figuring out how pointers work, so i don't know why this error appears to me :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myPtr(int *nbr)
{
    nbr = (void *)142;
    printf("%d",nbr);
}
int main()
{
    int *p;
     myPtr(p);
}
```

Comment: What is this program supposed to do?

Comment: printf("%d",nbr);  => printf("%p", (void *)nbr);

Comment: Since `nbr` parameter is declared as `int *nbr` it doesn't sound so surprising..

Comment: @lilDer Do you mean it gives the `int` (that is pointed to) the value 142? To do that, you should _dereference_ the pointer, like this: `*nbr = 142;`, and print the value from the dereferenced pointer like this: `printf("%d", *nbr);`.

Comment: @ian-abbott Yes that what im obligated to do but i find Pointers so hard to understand, and yes i try it like that and i GOT "Segmentation fault"

Comment: @lilDer The "Segmentation fault" probably occurred because the pointer was uninitialized and not pointing to valid memory. In `main()`, you could define an `int` variable, e.g. `int a;` and point `p` to it, `p = &a;`. Then `myPtr(p)` can safely dereference the pointer because it is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several of things going on in your program.  Let's start with this:  Think of a pointer as an address in computer memory.  In you main(), you're saying "p is an address of a place to store an integer" ... in most implementations, that would be 4 bytes.  But p currently doesn't have a value.

In your myPtr() routine, you set that address to 142:  you're telling the program that address 0x000008e (the hex equivalent of 142) is 4 bytes of memory for an integer ... but you don't know what's stored at that address.

The printf() format specifier, "%d", says you're going to pass an integer ... but what you pass is a pointer to memory, which is why you're getting that warning.  If what you wanted to do was print the address, you could use the format "%p", which tells printf() you are, indeed, passing a pointer.

If, on the other hand, you want to print a number, you need to dereference the pointer:

```
printf("%d", *nbr);
```

The problem you'll hit with that on most systems is that you'll get a memory access error:  address 0x0000008e (142) is in a protected memory page on most systems ("page 0"), and you can't normally read or write that memory.

I think you need to find a good on-line tutorial on C pointers, taking the address of a variable with &, and accessing the pointer with *.

Answer (score 0):

nbr is of type int *, that is it is a pointer to an address in memory and dereferencing the pointer to get its value will return an int.

I would recommend the following modifications to your code, both in the myPtr function:

Firstly, to set nbr to point at a location in memory which contains the integer 142, use:

```
nbr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*nbr = 142;
```

The first line allocates memory for that pointer, the second dereferences the pointer and sets the value at that address to 142.

Secondly, change the print statement to use the value rather than the address, like so:

```
printf("%d",*nbr);
```

You get the error for printing nbr and not *nbr because nbr is of type int *, while %d wants an int and not an int pointer.

This is all assuming you wanted to print out the value 142. If you wanted to print out something else, my changes will not cause that to happen.

I hope I have answered your question somewhere in there, good luck with C!